# Issue with python mod-wsgi

Tags: python, mod-wsgi

I can't run python scrip.

This can we because of version of wsgi? If yes were i can get needed wsgi version.

Error:

```
[Sun Jul 09 12:50:24.187917 2017] [wsgi:warn] [pid 20092] mod_wsgi: Compiled for Python/2.7.8.
[Sun Jul 09 12:50:24.187945 2017] [wsgi:warn] [pid 20092] mod_wsgi: Runtime using Python/2.7.9.
[Sun Jul 09 12:50:24.189601 2017] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 20092] AH00163: Apache/2.4.10 (Debian) mod_wsgi/4.3.0 Python/2.7.9 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sun Jul 09 12:50:24.189617 2017] [core:notice] [pid 20092] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Sun Jul 09 12:50:29.102086 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 20098] [client x] mod_wsgi (pid=20098): Target WSGI script '/var/www/get5-web/get5.wsgi' cannot be loaded as Python module.
[Sun Jul 09 12:50:29.102112 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 20098] [client x] mod_wsgi (pid=20098): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/var/www/get5-web/get5.wsgi'.
[Sun Jul 09 12:50:29.102125 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 20098] [client x] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Sun Jul 09 12:50:29.102135 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 20098] [client x]   File "/var/www/get5-web/get5.wsgi", line 15, in <module>
[Sun Jul 09 12:50:29.102170 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 20098] [client x]     from get5 import app as application
[Sun Jul 09 12:50:29.102177 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 20098] [client x]   File "/var/www/get5-web/get5/__init__.py", line 68, in <module>
[Sun Jul 09 12:50:29.102224 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 20098] [client x]     app.config['LOG_PATH'], when='midnight')
[Sun Jul 09 12:50:29.102231 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 20098] [client x]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/handlers.py", line 171, in __init__
[Sun Jul 09 12:50:29.102398 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 20098] [client x]     BaseRotatingHandler.__init__(self, filename, 'a', encoding, delay)
[Sun Jul 09 12:50:29.102406 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 20098] [client x]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/handlers.py", line 64, in __init__
[Sun Jul 09 12:50:29.102415 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 20098] [client x]     logging.FileHandler.__init__(self, filename, mode, encoding, delay)
[Sun Jul 09 12:50:29.102419 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 20098] [client x]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 911, in __init__
[Sun Jul 09 12:50:29.102633 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 20098] [client x]     StreamHandler.__init__(self, self._open())
[Sun Jul 09 12:50:29.102640 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 20098] [client x]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 936, in _open
[Sun Jul 09 12:50:29.102648 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 20098] [client x]     stream = open(self.baseFilename, self.mode)
[Sun Jul 09 12:50:29.102659 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 20098] [client x] IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/var/www/get5-web/logs/get5.log'
```

Thanks.

Comment: While opening log file, you get `Permission denied: '/var/www/get5-web/logs/get5.log'`. Check Apache has write permissions to `/var/www/get5-web/logs/` and make sure that directory exists.

Comment: Details of access right permissions of Apache and this issue are documented in http://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/application-issues.html#access-rights-of-apache-user Usually it is better to send logging to stdout/stderr and use Apache logging mechanism and file rotation.